# Docker image pull fails and makes docker daemon inaccessible until machine restart

Tags: docker

I am facing a strange issue with the docker image pull command where the command fails with this error;

```
[desai@brilp0017 ~]$ docker image pull nginx:latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
d121f8d1c412: Extracting [==================================================>]  
27.09MB/27.09MB
ebd81fc8c071: Download complete 
655316c160af: Download complete 
d15953c0e0f8: Download complete 
2ee525c5c3cc: Download complete 
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error cleaning up after pivot: remove /.pivot_root534731447: device or resource busy
```

After this error the docker daemon is no longer accessible and all docker commands return following error;

```
[desai@brilp0017 ~]$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

The command `systemctl status docker` however shows it as running;

```
[desai@brilp0017 ~]$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-09-11 14:25:53 BST; 14min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
    Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Main PID: 2380 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 14
    Memory: 249.5M
    CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
            └─2380 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

The journalctl log has the same error line as encountered in the pull command;

```
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.345006155+01:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.348597478+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.348667479+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.348733420+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.348765306+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.353865701+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.353908904+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.353944835+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.353988191+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.497701794+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.816295801+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.816318357+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Sep 11 14:25:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:52.816442165+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Sep 11 14:25:53 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:53.101411528+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Sep 11 14:25:53 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:53.125378601+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Sep 11 14:25:53 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:53.291896277+01:00" level=warning msg="Not using native diff for overlay2, this may cause degraded performance for building images: kernel has CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR enabled" storage-driver=overlay2
Sep 11 14:25:53 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:53.292711063+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=48a66213fe graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.12-ce
Sep 11 14:25:53 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:53.293190069+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Sep 11 14:25:53 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:25:53.340381428+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Sep 11 14:25:53 brilp0017 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 11 14:32:38 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:32:38.011501405+01:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Sep 11 14:33:11 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:33:11.592234770+01:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Sep 11 14:34:52 brilp0017 dockerd[2380]: time="2020-09-11T14:34:52.864254519+01:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error cleaning up after pivot: remove /.pivot_root534731447: device or resource busy"
```

After this the error remains the same even after stopping and starting docker service multiple times with `systemctl`. After restarting the laptop fully and starting the docker service it starts work as expected until the next time docker pull command is used.

I have searched for solution on the internet but majority of them point to the user not being in docker group but that is not the case for me;

```
[desai@brilp0017 ~]$ groups
sys network power vboxusers wireshark sambashare docker lp wheel desai
```

Here is the output of `docker version` before it crashes for version details;

```
[desai@brilp0017 ~]$ docker version
Client:
Version:           19.03.12-ce
API version:       1.40
Go version:        go1.14.5
Git commit:        48a66213fe
Built:             Sat Jul 18 01:33:21 2020
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server:
Engine:
Version:          19.03.12-ce
API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:       go1.14.5
Git commit:       48a66213fe
Built:            Sat Jul 18 01:32:59 2020
OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Experimental:     false
containerd:
Version:          v1.4.0.m
GitCommit:        09814d48d50816305a8e6c1a4ae3e2bcc4ba725a.m
runc:
Version:          1.0.0-rc92
GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
docker-init:
Version:          0.18.0
GitCommit:        fec3683
```

I am using Manjaro linux OS;

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.73.0
Qt Version: 5.15.0
Kernel Version: 4.19.141-2-MANJARO
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by updating the kernel to 5.4 version.